# TIPA problem with the symbol n with right leg

Tags: fonts, errors, symbols, linguistics, tipa

I can type all symbols with the TIPA package but not the n with the right leg. I usually use `\textipa{code of the symbol}` and it works with all codes I tried in the TIPA manual but not with the `\textnrleg`. I even tried copying the words from the manual an then put it in `\textipa{}` but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}


\begin{document}

Grad der Öffnung

\begin{easylist}[itemize]

& semi-ouvert [\textipa{E}]
& [\textipa{Z}]
& [\textipa{K}]
& [\textipa{\textltailn}]
& [\textipa{\~E}]
& [\textipa{\textnrleg}]

\end{easylist}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This character is only available if you also load the `tipx` package.  So you should use:

```
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
```

This is documented, but easy to miss in the documentation. The list of symbols in the `tipx` package is given in Appendix B.  In the introduction to the Annotated List of Symbols (Appendix A) the following line shows up:

> In the case of a symbol from `tipx` fonts, the code number is underlined.

You can see this here:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A Unicode version of the solution (compiled with lualatex or xelatex) looks like:

[image: Noto Sans font]

Any suitable Unicode font could be used.

e.g., CMU Serif:

[image: CMU Serif font]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
%%\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\fipa{Noto Sans}[Colour=red]
\newfontfamily\fipab{CMU Serif}%'tipa font'
\newcommand\directipa[1]{{\fipa #1}}
\newcommand\mytilde{^^^^0303}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

%\usepackage{tipa}
\providecommand\XeTeXpicfile{ROSS, grmmble:-)}% with luatex that means "pretending" to be xetex just while you load the package
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357686/does-fontspec-no-longer-provide-the-textipa-command
\usepackage{xunicode}
\def\useTIPAfont{\fipa}

\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}


\begin{document}

Grad der Öffnung

\begin{easylist}[itemize]

& semi-ouvert [\textipa{E}]; direct input = [\directipa{ɛ}]%\directipa for the font
& [\textipa{Z}]; direct input = [\directipa{ʒ}]
& [\textipa{K}]; direct input = [\directipa{ʁ}]
& [\textipa{\textltailn}]; direct input = [\directipa{ɲ}]
& [\textipa{\~E}]; direct input = [\directipa{ɛ^^^^0303}] or [\directipa{ɛ\mytilde}] or [\directipa{ɛ̃}]
& [\textipa{\textnrleg}]; direct input = [\directipa{ƞ}]

\end{easylist}

\newpage
\def\useTIPAfont{\fipab}

Grad der Öffnung

\begin{easylist}[itemize]

& semi-ouvert [\textipa{E}]
& [\textipa{Z}]
& [\textipa{K}]
& [\textipa{\textltailn}]
& [\textipa{\~E}]
& [\textipa{\textnrleg}]

\end{easylist}


\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*

Direct input can be used as well, since it is already Unicode. MWE has been updated.

[image: direct input]