# Does fontspec no longer provide the \textipa command?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, tipa

I'm using a freshly updated install of texlive on Linux.

Recently, I was revisiting an old project that I migrated from `pdfTeX` to `LuaTeX`. One thing that was immense help was that the original code made heavy use of the `tipa` package. Fontspec used to provide a `\textipa` command which emulated the behavior of `tipa`'s ASCII-based input method. However, trying to compile my unchanged document now no longer works: it complains that there's no such command as `\textipa`. Here's a minimal (non) working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\textipa{N}
\end{document}
```

It's not practical for me to convert my code, and I kind of liked being able to use ASCII based input. Is there any way to get this functionality back?

Comment: `fontspec` has never provided the command; it was `xunicode` to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fontspec never really defined the tipa commands, it loaded `xunicode` for other reasons and these got defined as a side effect.  You can use the `[euenc]` option to `fontspec` to make it use the old encoding setup but better probably would just be to load `xunicode` explicitly if you need that.

Unfortunately with luatex that means "pretending" to be xetex just while you load the package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\providecommand\XeTeXpicfile{ROSS, grmmble:-)}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\begin{document}
\textipa{N}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So fontspec would sometimes implictly load xunicode? because I did a search across the repo's entire history, and the string ``xunicode`` never shows up once.

Comment: @KevinKeith  yes if using EU1 or EU2 encoding it always loads xunicode, that was the default until this year.