# While using package gb4e all the dental marks in IPA go berserk

Tags: errors, linguistics, gb4e, tipa

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
 \ex

 \gll \noautomath \textipa{\|[to} pani pito\\
 ram.3P.M.Sg. water.F.Sg. drink.PERF.M.Sg.\\
 \trans ram drinks water


\end{exe} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you mind to explain your question a little bit more? :-}

Comment: You can load tipa after gb4e, but perhaps you then a clash somewhere else ...

Answer (score 11):

This is caused by a bug in `gb4e` that arose after changes to the LaTeX kernel a few years ago.  The solution is to add.

```
\makeatletter
\def\new@fontshape{}
\makeatother
```

**before** you load `gb4e`.

But additionally, you need to load `tipa` *after* `gb4e` since `gb4e` also defines `\|`. (Thanks to Ulrike for noticing this.)

Here's a full example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\makeatletter
\def\new@fontshape{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
 \ex
 \gll  \textipa{\|[to} pani pito\\
 ram.3P.M.Sg. water.F.Sg. drink.PERF.M.Sg.\\
 \trans ram drinks water
\end{exe} 


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer by @AlanMunn,

`\textipa` can use Unicode (via `xunicode` package), but direct input is easier.

Either way, system fonts can then be used (via `fontspec` package).

Compile with xelatex or lualatex.

[image: direct input Unicode]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\fipamain{Noto Serif}[Colour=blue]
\newfontfamily\fipa{Noto Sans}[Colour=red]
\newfontfamily\fipab{CMU Serif}%'tipa font'


\makeatletter
\def\new@fontshape{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
%\usepackage{tipa}
\providecommand\XeTeXpicfile{ROSS, grmmble:-)}% with luatex that means "pretending" to be xetex just while you load the package
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357686/does-fontspec-no-longer-provide-the-textipa-command
\usepackage{xunicode}
\def\useTIPAfont{\fipamain}%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358118/tipa-tone-bar-glyph-missing-with-xecjk

\usepackage{nomencl}

\begin{document}

\textbackslash textipa\{\} input:

\begin{exe}
 \ex
 \gll  \textipa{\|[to} pani pito\\
 ram.3P.M.Sg. water.F.Sg. drink.PERF.M.Sg.\\
 \trans ram drinks water
\end{exe} 

Direct input:

\begin{exe}
 \ex
 \gll  t̪o pani pito\\
 ram.3P.M.Sg. water.F.Sg. drink.PERF.M.Sg.\\
 \trans ram drinks water
\end{exe} 


\end{document}
```